# Why should a planned power outage be expected to damage equipment?

Tags: power, mains

There is a planned power outage in the San Francisco Bay Area in the upcoming days.

News media [reports](https://abc7news.com/society/pg-e-power-shutdown-timeline-when-your-power-could-come-back/5603844/) that the utility company (PG&E) says it expects that the *"shutdown will damage some of its equipment and that restoration could take days"*.

My question is, why should such damage occur during a *planned* outage? Is this normal?

Comment: Media reports and engineering reasons are usually incompatible. Go ask them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not on electronics design.

Comment: @TonyM: Is this site about electrical engineering (including power etc.) or just about (micro)electronics?

Comment: @Tony M `We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics` https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Jasen, ...plus the rest of it in 'on-topic', which elaborates beyond those few words you've copied.

Comment: we get questions about electrical engineering here from time to time. given the name of this SX it's hard to call them off-topic.

Comment: That's not in the news report I read, The one I read stated something like it could be a few days because the power equipment needed to be inspected and could take a few days. Whatever the reason this is a fairly common "cover your butt" practice implemented for customers. You need to let customers know the worst case scenario. Is it going to take days for it to come up? Most likely not. But you get in trouble if you don't let people expect the worst case scenario.

Comment: I'm with Voltage Spike on this one. Things that have been working properly and continuously are more likely to fail when their operating state is changed than if the status quo is just continued. That's just a fact of life.

Comment: "PG&E cautioned that its workers may need up to five days, after the dangerous weather passes, **to inspect lines for damage** and restore all power. With winds expected to slow on Thursday, that means the current outages could last as long as until next Tuesday." https://www.sfchronicle.com/california-wildfires/article/PG-E-power-shut-offs-Here-s-what-you-need-to-14501255.php

Comment: The now offline report from the company itself, available from cache confirmswhat @BruceAbbott says https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CVT96D3c_YgJ:https://www.pge.com/en/about/newsroom/newsdetails/index.page%3Ftitle%3D20191007_pge_continues_to_monitor_a_significant_wednesdaythursday_wind_event_public_safety_power_shutoff_could_impact_more_than_600000_customers_across_northern_and_central_california+&cd=12&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr

Comment: So you guys are saying it's not the *shutdown* that would damage equipment but rather the wind (i.e. ABC7 probably misreported)?

Answer (score 1):

PG&E is shutting off power to prevent lines blown together by winds from sparking fires

My reading of that report suggests that PG&E also expects some damage to its power lines by the winds (and falling trees etc).

This means that when it's time to restore power some consumers may be left without power until the repairs can be made.